# Enter-PSSession WinRM cannot process the request

Tags: powershell, winrm

I have two computers in the domain.
I can successfully execute command:

```
Enter-PSSession "some computer name" -credentials $cred
```

But for one reason, I need to execute this command without the credential, like this:

```
Enter-PSSession "some computer name"
```

But when I execute this command I see the error:

> Enter-PSSession : Connecting to remote server ... failed with the following error message : WinRM cannot process the request. The following error occurred while using Kerberos authentication: Cannot find the computer .... Verify that the computer exists on
>   the network and that the name provided is spelled correctly. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + Enter-PSSession "..."

What should I do to fix this issue? 
I know, that trusted host is *.
But remote computer somewhere required a credential.
Could you please advice what is missing?

Comment: can you successfully `ping "some computer name"`? It says it does not find the computer

Comment: Do you mean that with the credentials it find the computer, but without them it doesn't?

Comment: yes. I can ping successfully remote computer. And yes, with credential it is working, without is not.